# React context - state not true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a project and got stucked at context file. I want my state `planet` to be true so i can use it in my component file. At the start it becomes true showing the right index of the array but in the end its becoming undefined. Can someone point me out what is causing "planet" state to be undefined at the end? Im talking about if statement - `if (planet) {...}`. Im attaching  code from context file and screen of my browser console. Would be nice if someone also told me if i can change state in its own setting function e.g. `setPlanets(planet[0])`.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const Context = React.createContext({
  onChooseMoon: () => {},
  onChooseMars: () => {},
});

const ContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [planet, setPlanets] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("./data.json")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const transformedData = data.destinations.map((destination) => {
          return {
            name: destination.name,
            img: destination.images.png,
            desc: destination.description,
            dist: destination.distance,
            travel: destination.travel,
          };
        });
        setPlanets(transformedData);
      });
  }, []);

  if (planet) {
    setPlanets(planet[0]);
    console.log(planet[0]);
    console.log("hello");
  }

  const setMoonHandler = () => {
    setPlanets(planet[0]);
  };

  const setMarsHandler = () => {
    setPlanets(planet[1]);
  };

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        planet: planet,
        onChooseMoon: setMoonHandler,
        onChooseMars: setMarsHandler,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContextProvider;
```

[image]

Comment: In the fetch you are assigning an array to planet, but in the other `setPlanets` is an `Object` why dont you keep the schema consistent?

Comment: `setPlanets(planet[0]);` here "planet" is an array, and you reasing the same planet as an Object. using the same Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of what's going on:

1. Component mounts, value of `planet` is `undefined`, `useEffect` is triggered. When `useEffect` runs `setPlanets(transformedData)` rerender is triggered.
2. Value of `planet` is now whatever `transformedData` was (I'm assuming an array of planet objects). Since `planet` is truthy, `setPlanets(planet[0])` runs, causing a rerender.
3. Value of `planet` is now whatever `transformedData[0]` was (a single planet). Since `planet` is still truthy, `setPlanets(planet[0])` runs again, causing a rerender.
4. Value of `planet` is now whatever `transformedData[0][0]` was. Since `transformedData[0]` was not an array and probably doesn't have the key `0`, the value of `planet` is now `undefined` again.

The issue is that if ever `planet` becomes defined, running `setPlanet(planet[0])` will run until the value of `planet` becomes `undefined` again.

I think what you meant to do (judging by the naming) was to have two separate state variables. One to hold all of the planets, and one to hold a single (active/focused) planet.

Here's an example:

```
const ContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [activePlanet, setActivePlanet] = useState();
  const [planets, setPlanets] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("./data.json") // same as before
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!activePlanet && planets.length > 0) {
        setActivePlanet(planets[0]);
        console.log(planets[0]);
        console.log("hello");
    }
  }, [activePlanet, planets]);

  // ...
};
```

Also it's generally a good idea to wrap all state updating logic in hooks (or tied to events like clicks), so I've added a `useEffect` to wrap the `setActivePlanet` call.

Comment: Thats perfect explanation. Thank you sir!